# web scraping for a retail website using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, web-scraping

I have a fairly working code, however i want to modify the code. The idea was to go to a website, input the item and fetch the price to the excel. However i could only hard code it. I want the VBA to do it for 50 items and fetch the price for the items into excel at one click so that it would pick each cell item and search the website and paste into the excel and do it for the 50 to 100 items. Once the website is navigated, the code should pick each item from a column and search the web and extract the price and paste to the corresponding items.

I tried using for loop for the items for a column. I am seriously stuck in the loop.....;)

```
Sub webextract()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer        
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    Dim HTMLdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument        
    Dim HTMLinput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement        
    Dim HTMLbuttons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection        
    Dim HTMLbutton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement        
    Dim HTMLprice As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'searchterm = InputBox("ENTER TIM'S SEARCH TERM")        
    searchterm = Worksheets("AAP").Range("A9").Value
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "Enter the Web address"

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE 
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
    Set HTMLinput = HTMLdoc.getElementById("aap-960-search-input")
    HTMLinput.Value = searchterm

    Set HTMLbuttons = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("icons8-search")
    HTMLbuttons.Item.Click

    'code to extract the price and put in the excel sheet
    'Set HTMLprice = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("aap-pla-productprice__price red-price")

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE        
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        DoEvents
    Loop

    'On Error GoTo Errorhandler        
    Dim htmlEle1 As IHTMLElement
    Set dat = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("aap-pla-productprice__price red-price")

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        DoEvents
    Loop

    For Each elm In dat
        If elm.innerText <> "" Then
            'Debug.Print elm.innerText
             Worksheets("AAP").Range("C9").Value = elm.innerText
        End If
    Next

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the website address, a couple of test input values and expected output values?

Comment: The website is" https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/" and few part numbers are L10111,L10241,L12222,L14006,L14459,L14460 for the test input values.....Thank you!!!

Comment: And the expected return value for say L10111 would be $6.99 ?

Comment: yes...exactly!!!

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated.....Thanks!!!

Comment: I will have a look again tonight. There are time based cookies which affect using xhr but browser based should be easy enough.